# Why is there a field in a circuit when connects two ends of wire to positive and negative terminal of the battery?

Tags: electric-circuits

If there is any sort of field in a conductor, then the charge would rearrange such that the field is canceled. Then, why is it that there is electron flow in the circuit? Or is it that at each point the 'charge' density is same at all points?

Comment: Note: There can be no electric field inside a _perfect_ conductor, but ordinary room-temperature metals are not perfect conductors. They have resistance, and when current flows in a metallic conductor, there must be a small voltage gradient along the path of the current. _Superconductors,_ on the other hand, are a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The time taken for a conductor to to respond to the external field is finite. It depends on the geometry and the material properties, basically conductivity altogether and the applied field profile.

The flow happening in the case of battery and wire is exactly the system’s response to zero out the field. Only that the response time is high due to the geometrical constraint.